# URL Rewrite from one Host to another

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite all URL from a host, host1 (`www.host1.com`) to a new new host, host2 (`www.host2.com`). I want all the folders and subfolders of host1 to redirect to the main page of host2. That means www.host1.com/test.php should redirect to www.host1.com

```
 <rule name="Test Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www\.)?host1.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.host2.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
```

It seems my pattern is incorrect because it does not redirect when the url is www.host1.com/test.php but does when it is just www.host1.com. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What about this? See if this will get what you want.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="CustomRule">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.newsite\.com$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newsite.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```